# Inserting text inputted from a form into database, am I doing it securely?

Tags: php, mysql, security, mysqli

With phpMyAdmin I create a MySQL database for usage with a simple form where the user inputs text and I save it into a table.

I'm not massively experienced with security so I want to make sure I'm doing things right.

Basically, for accessing the database in code, I created a user with only privileges to insert into the database. That's it. I log in with that user in the code to insert the data.

However, in the code I log in with seemingly plain text, which I'm quite sure is a bad idea. I use `new mysqli(...)` to log in, and I just supply the user and password as a string. Is this plain text and a security issue? If so, how should I be doing it?

And I'm storing user email addresses. I escape the data to prevent injection attacks, but do I need to store it hashed like I would a password?

Thanks, I just want to make sure I'm handling the security side of this appropriately. Is there anything else I should be keeping in mind?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Storing emails hashed can often be a pain, and not usually necessary, although it depends on your site/functions/services etc. IE a government site with a certain security level requirement may want the email addresses encrypting as they may be high ranking council officers (etc).
It really does depend on the individual scenario.

Passwords - never store in plain text, ever. Even if making your own little login for your own site admin or whatever, it's good practice to do things right, plus this will help you learn and also generate template code which can be re-used on others sites/projects.

If you show your login code we can take a look.

On any user input code you should validate the data is what is acceptable and what you are expecting. Even your own login area, as while you obviously wont be hacking yourself, it's still good practice doing things right and again gives you template code for public areas (also you never know who might get access to your login area). 
Using PHP functions like strlen(), is_numeric(), and some regex to check inputted data is ok (ie max or min character lengths, can only enter numeric, or alpha numeric etc).
This is also used to maintain databases, as if you have a column that's varchar(20), using strlen to check user input is 20 avoids any DB issues too.

As you're already using MYSQLI, I suggest looking into crypt blowfish, it's pretty straight forward and is a modern secure way to store and retrieve passwords.

A very basic intro to using crypt and blowfish:

```
require('PasswordHash.php');//you download this file, and just include it
//it contains all the hashing engine etc

// $PostPassword is the one they entered in a form (etc)
$CreateHash = new PasswordHash(8, FALSE);
$HashPassword = $CreateHash->HashPassword($PostPassword);

// $HashPassword is the hashed and salted password you store in the db
// (should always be 60 chars, check with strlen)
// Don't use your own salt, it's not worth it 
// and you end up having to use it/store it/remember it
// when checking their password for login etc.
// just use the built in blowfish random salting algos


// Then to check their pass (ie login)
// Query and select their password from DB ($DbPass)
// with their username entered in the login form
// Check it against the password they entered in form
// (CheckPassword salts/hashes automatically to match the DB one)

$CreateHash = new PasswordHash(8, FALSE);

$CheckPass = $CreateHash->CheckPassword($PostPassword, $DbPass);
if ($CheckPass)
  {
    // password matches
  }
else
  {
    //not match, tell them to try again etc
  }

// you can use various checks on this, mainly check if the 
// library exists (to avoid php errors etc)
if(defined("CRYPT_BLOWFISH") && CRYPT_BLOWFISH) 
  {
    // do all your password stuff
  }
```

You'd have other checks before doing that above, eg strlen etc, then once you're happy the data is valid, you can store it in the db.

You should also use prepared statements on data base queries, as this is a very secure method.

Answer (score -1):

Storing personally identifiable information in clear text is never a good idea. You can't use a hash unless it's a two way hash. It doesn't necessarily need to be encrypted, but it should at least be obscured.

Comment: What are practical measures one can take based on your answer? In this particular case I mean.

Answer (score -2):

> I just want to make sure I'm handling the security side of this appropriately.

Nope, you aren't.

> I created a user with only privileges to insert

This one is quite a useless measure.

> I log in with seemingly plain text, which I'm quite sure is a bad idea.

It is not. Strictly speaking, you have no other way.

> do I need to store email hashed like I would a password?

There is no way to get email back from hash, mind you. If you don't need email for it's purpose - just don't ask users for it. If you need to send emails - there is no other way but plain text.

> I escape the data to prevent injection attacks

### This. Is what you are doing wrong.

Escaping is no way intended for protecting against attacks and should never be used for this purpose.

> Is there anything else I should be keeping in mind?

A lot.
But regarding SQL security, there should be a strict rule:

### Every variable should go into a query via prepared statement only.

Comment: while it's useless hashing emails, you can encrypt them. It happens in the real world, as I said below, depending on security requirements.